# Using Predis to store form data

Tags: php, redis, predis

I tried using `lpush`

```
$list = "flavors";
$array = array($_GET["mainid"], $_GET["flavor1"], $_GET["flavor2"], $_GET["flavor3"]);
$redis = new Predis\Client();
$redis->lpush($list,implode("", $array));
echo $redis->lrange(0, -1);
```

I have tried using `hset`

```
$redis->hset("flavors", $_GET["mainid"], $_GET["mainid"]);
$redis->hset("flavors", $_GET['mainid'] . "flavor1", $_GET["flavor1"]);
$redis->hset("flavors", $_GET['mainid'] . "flavor2", $_GET["flavor2"]);
$redis->hset("flavors", $_GET['mainid'] . "flavor3", $_GET["flavor3"]);
echo $redis->hgetall($_GET['mainid']);
```

But I can't get that to work because I get this error: http://pastie.org/8401717

How could I fix that? I think it is something about being given an array when it expects a string, but I have `implode` in there, so why else isn't it working? If it can't work at all, what other Redis data type could I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got that error when using `lpush` because the `flavors` key is already stored with a different Redis data type. So you should delete that key before you try again.

You also used `lpush` in wrong way. You should try this:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $redis->lpush($list, $value);
}
```

Or if your redis api support multi params:

```
call_user_func_array(array($redis, 'lpush'), array_merge($list, $array));
```

If you want to store flavors by `mainid`, you may want to store it with multi keys and use `lpush`:

```
$list = "flavor:{$_GET['mainid']}";
$redis->lpush($list, $_GET["flavor1"]);
$redis->lpush($list, $_GET["flavor2"]);
$redis->lpush($list, $_GET["flavor3"]);
```

Another way is to store in a single hash and using json_encode (don't use implode):

```
$data = json_encode(array($_GET["flavor1"], $_GET["flavor2"], $_GET["flavor3"]));
$redis->hset('flavors', $_GET["mainid"], $data);
```